# Logs not coming for endpoint being created in sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to create an endpoint via sagemaker. The status of the endpoint goes to failed with the message "The primary container for production variant variantName did not pass the ping health check. Please check CloudWatch logs for this endpoint".

But there are no logs created to check.

Blocked on this from quite some time, is anyone aware why this could be happening

Comment: can you try calling it (locally) using the Python SageMaker SDK? it will display more info in your local console

Comment: My endpoint logs become available in cloudwatch very very slowly, at least 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You have missed defining the `ping()` method in your `model_handler.py` file.

The model_handler.py file must define two methods, like this -

```
custom_handler = CustomHandler()

# define your own health check for the model over here
def ping():
    return "healthy"


def handle(request, context): # context is necessary input otherwise Sagemaker will throw exception
    if request is None:
        return "SOME DEFAULT OUTPUT"
    try:
        response = custom_handler.predict_fn(request)
        return [response] # Response must be a list otherwise Sagemaker will throw exception

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Prediction failed for request: {}. \n'
                     .format(request) + 'Error trace :: {} \n'.format(str(e)))
```

You should look at the reference code in the accepted [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69828187/sagemaker-inference-container-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-model-handle/69927107#69927107).